# Jquery to parse HTML in a string

Tags: php, jquery

I tried searching the related posts, and having a hard time figuring out how to fix my query - I'm pretty close, any help is much appreciated (new to Jquery).

I program in PHP, and trying to pull either the HREF value from a  tag, or the text.  Either will work.

I basically have my HTML code in a string, might contain multiple  tags, and would like to load the text of the  tags into either a PHP array or variable (right now just trying to ALERT the results, I can dump it later).

My PHP Code:

```
<?php
$info = '<li><strong><a href="http://www.mysite.com/test.html" title="Some stuff">I want this text</a></strong>';

echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo '$("document").ready( function () {';
echo 'alert($("a", $("' . $info . '")).html());';
echo '});';
echo '</script>';
?>
```

The above doesn't alert anything.  Putting in

```
echo 'alert("yes")';
```

does work, so I'm guessing there's something basic wrong with my syntax, but 4 hours later still unable to find it! :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SLaks** has the rest of your problem. But also, it's not:

```
$("document").ready();
```

It's:

```
$(document).ready();
```

The former is a selector for a tag named `<document>`.

Answer (score 5):

You aren't Javascript-escaping the quotes in your string.

Your code creates Javascript that looks like

```
$("<li>...<a href="http..."...")
```

The quotes in the attribute end the Javascript string, creating a syntax error.

You need to call `json_encode`.

Comment: json_encode($info);  it adds slashes but still doesn't look right

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready( function () {

      alert($("a", $(""<li><strong><a href=\"http:\/\/www.mysite.com\/test.html\" title=\"Some stuff\">I want this text<\/a><\/strong><\/li>"")).html());

      });

     </script>

Comment: Bingo.  Works.  And if my HTML string has multiple <a> tags and I want to get the .each, then i dump .each at the end of my jquery?  like this:  alert($("a", $(<?php echo $info; ?>)).html().each);   ?

Comment: No.  You need to pass an anonymous function to `.each` which calls `alert($(this).html())`.

Comment: Cool thanks. I gotta run out of the office but will add that when I get back.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I feel like this should work -but returns nothing:     $(document).ready( function () {
 $("a", $(<?php echo $info; ?>)).each(
          function() {
        alert($(this).html());
   }
       );
      };

Answer (score 2):

This should work the way you want it to:

```
<?php
$info = '<li><strong><a href="http://www.mysite.com/test.html" title="Some stuff">I want this text</a></strong></li>';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
        alert($("a", $("<?php echo $info; ?>")).html());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks - tried the above - still not giving me an alert though. My code, in code view, looks weird like i'm still not enclosing correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing your li Tag

```
$info = '<li><strong><a href="http://www.mysite.com/test.html" title="Some stuff">I want this text</a></strong>';
```

should be

```
$info = '<li><strong><a href="http://www.mysite.com/test.html" title="Some stuff">I want this text</a></strong></li>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should escape info. It's breaking because you've got double quotes inside of double quotes:

```
$info = addslashes($info);
```

or

```
$info = json_encode($info);
```

or just

```
$info = str_replace('"', '\\"');
```

Comment: Thanks for the input - did the middle suggestion about json_encode($info) but it drops slashes into my HMTL output as well, must be that my host has magic_quotes on or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the HTML is a JS variable first, then use it.  Also, heredocs are your friend.

```
<?php
$info = '<li><strong><a href="http://www.mysite.com/test.html" title="Some stuff">I want this text</a></strong></li>';

echo <<<END
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  var HTML = '$info';
  alert($('a', $(HTML)).html());
});
</script>
END;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
        var info = \''.$info.'\';
        $("a").html(info);
        alert(info);
    });
</script>';
```

Comment: that's close, almost works - it alerts the entire info string - if i just want the text in the <a> tags, the jquery needs to be where?  in the alert?